# How to send all log4net output to Serilog

Tags: log4net, serilog

I want to integrate Serilog in a CMS application which already uses log4net internally. I don't want to end up with checking two places to get an overview of all of the log files. Is there a way to send all of the log4net output from all loggers to Serilog? I can not find the right place to hook into and write the implementation.

Comment: Can you use https://github.com/joelweiss/Log4net.Appender.Serilog ?